# Graphviz: avoid overlapping edges and nodes

Tags: python, nodes, graphviz, edges

I know it's a recurrent question but I can't find a working answer in my case.
I have a graph with 365 nodes to plot correctly.[image: tree]
For now, the result is almost satisfying, but not perfect. As you can see, some edges cross each other, and some nodes overlap. I would like to avoid that, and I'm pretty sure it's possible, there is a lot of free space available for a better organization. I use the graphviz_layout function with NetworkX. Would you have any idea ?

Here is a working example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import pygraphviz
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)

inp = "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"

chains = re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)", inp)
bp = [int(value) for value in re.findall("([0-9]+)", inp)]

while G.number_of_nodes() < len(chains[0]):
    G.add_node(G.number_of_nodes() + 1)
    G.add_edge(G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_nodes() - 1)

for number, sequence in zip(bp, chains[1:]):
    G.add_node(G.number_of_nodes() + 1)
    G.add_edge(number, G.number_of_nodes())

    for res in sequence[:-1]:
        G.add_node(G.number_of_nodes() + 1)
        G.add_edge(G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_nodes() - 1)

pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G)

fig = plt.figure(1)

nx.draw(G, pos)

fig.set_size_inches(50, 50)
plt.savefig('tree.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```